# Launching JAR file from network

Tags: java, networking, jar, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I have a small problem regarding launching JAR file from network. My scenario is this:

Shared network directory on server with my app. Clients are running a JAR file from this network location. Everything works fine unless anybody looses his connection to the server.

When the app (JAR) is running on client machine and the connection goes down, any class that has never been used before gets used, a NoClassDefFoundError exception is thrown.

I know that JVM loads classes at runtime when they are needed. So my questions are:

1. **Can I somehow tell the JVM before launching the app, to load whole JAR (all classes in the JAR) into memory?** *I can't use Class.for("...") or any other way to load one class, because I "do not know" about all the classes.*
2. **Can I somehow tell the JVM to cache the JAR file ie. to temp folder on local harddrive?** *I do not want to have other app (JAR) which copies my app from network and then launches it.*
3. **Is there any other option for me, if I still want to have my JAR on shared network location?** :)

Comment: I am not sure but, did you check about the java webstart application?

Comment: That looks promissing! Thank you Keerthi, I'll give it a try.

Comment: So I ended up writing my own simple updater, which will check the program JAR on network, downloads it (if the version is higher) and launches it. The Java Webstart technology didn't serve my purposes. Thanks Keerthi

Comment: Happy that you were able to do it. Welcome :)